# magento custom payment gateway notification

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, payment-gateway

I am working on a custom payment solution and am stuck on how to notify magento that the payment was accepted or declined.

I have a `PaymentController.php` file and need to enter code to handle this.

The payment gateway provides a `HTTP GET` request below.

`http://www.websitename.co.uk/mygateway/payment/response?SessionID=&Note=&Tariff=&Status=`

1. SessionID is a unique ID assigned by payment gateway
2. Note is the orderID which was generated by magento
3. Tariff is the price of the order in pence i.e. 100p
4. Status is the status of payment, there are about 10 different types and Status=100 is a successful payment and Status=200 is a failed payment

So it might be `http://www.websitename.co.uk/mygateway/payment/response?SessionID=123456&Note=1000051&Tariff=300&Status=100`

I am not sure how to create the code to handle this get request and work out the status

I need to place the code between this area of the `paymentcontroller`

```
public function responseAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        /*
        /* Your gateway's code to make sure the reponse you
        /* just got is from the gatway and not from some weirdo.
        /* This generally has some checksum or other checks,
        /* and is provided by the gateway.
        /* For now, we assume that the gateway's response is valid
        */

        $validated = true;
        $orderId = '';

        if($validated) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Zend_Http_Client` class.

You will find everything you need to know in this small tutorial from zend:

[http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.http.client.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.html)

A quick and dirty way would be:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://www.websitename.co.uk/mygateway/payment/response?SessionID=123456&Note=1000051&Tariff=300&Status=100');
$response = $client->request();
```

Then check the response and your good to go. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help Mischa Leiss. I have looked through the tutuorial but am fairly new to this and a bit stuck. Wondered if you could give me a bit more guidance based on my code above.

Comment: Thanks Mischa Leiss, I am still stuck on this. So the above code I would place before the if statement in my code? But how do I check the response and set this to be dynamic as the URL will have a different note (order number) and status each time. It is probably really obvious to solve but I am really stuck on this so would appreciate any more help you can give.